# Slice an SKShapeNode into two

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uibezierpath, skshapenode

Is there an easy method to slice an SKShapeNode into 2 seperate SKShapeNodes?

In this example I have created an SKShapeNode using a closed bezier path as well as a single line.

```
let squareShape = SKShapeNode()
    squareShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 256, height: 256), cornerRadius: 10).cgPath
    squareShape.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX-128, y: frame.midY+200-128)
    squareShape.fillColor = UIColor.green
    squareShape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    squareShape.lineWidth = 2
    addChild(squareShape)

    let lineShape1 = SKShapeNode()
    let line1 = UIBezierPath()
    line1.move(to: CGPoint(x: -200, y: 300))
    line1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100))
    lineShape1.path = line1.cgPath
    lineShape1.strokeColor = UIColor.white
    lineShape1.lineWidth = 2
    addChild(lineShape1)
```

How can I transform the existing SKShapeNode into 2 seperate SKShapeNodes separated by the line?

I need to be able to do this with varying line positions and shapes types (or even with multiple shapes and a single line).

Thanks

[image]